# CSS tabs using href

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

In school we had about 5 minutes left, so I decided to go on W3Schools on random tutorials. And found CSS tab tutorial. It was something like:

```
span {display: none;}
span:active {display: block;}
```

Basically, when: `<a href="#menu1">` was clicked, it would display: block the element that it has in href meaning, menu 1 would be displayed. The way it was made was somehow that you could add new ones easily, by adding new #id then putting `div` with that id, nothing had to be changed in CSS. It was about 10-20 lines in CSS too. Anyone know? I seriously need it. There was no JavaScript involved, or JQuery or anything like that.

Comment: No Javascript sounds strange. Is that a must for you?

Comment: Yes it is. It was that when you clicked html link using href="#idhere" css then would open that #idhere and all the other tabs, would be hidden all the time, until called. I remember it including :target somewhere. ;/

Comment: The problem is that this is impossible without JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but that sounds for the target technic for me. With CSS3 there is the `:target` Parameter available. With that you can add a css state, when they're selected via an anchor.

Here is a really simple example, what's the trick behind that.

```css
#contents div {
    border: 1px black dotted;
    display: none; //hides all div elements
}

#contents div:target {
    display: block; //shows the selected div (target)
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#content1">Menu 1</a>
        <a href="#content2">Menu 2</a>
        <a href="#content3">Menu 3</a>
        <a href="#content4">Menu 4</a>
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
        <div id="content1">Suspendisse potenti. Mauris in lacinia.</div>
        <div id="content2">Pellentesque pulvinar venenatis ante in.</div>
        <div id="content3">Vestibulum a nisi viverra, hendrerit.</div>
        <div id="content4">Nullam leo ipsum, euismod sed.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YES that is what i was looking for, the other code was little bit longer, but thank you so much for help !

Comment: Any way i can help you back ? I was looking for this for 4-5 weeks !

Comment: If this was the answer, a mark as answer would be enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of doing this without javascript. Active is a pseudo class meaning it represents the state of an element. That state would need to be set initially or you'd have to add a class of `active` which again would require javascript to add and remove. Maybe, your tacher didn't discuss the javascript part with you but here is a link that will show you how to do what you are looking for. 
http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp

EDIT:
Well i did find this js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/812ehkyf/ that is apparently css only. He is actually using input fields and using the 'checked' state which can be set initially in html. So check that out

Comment: i remember copying html and css from documents, and they were 100% working. And i didnt even touch javascript.

Answer (score 0):

here you got href:#img1 active view

```css
html,body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #222;
  color: #aaa;
  text-align:center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.2em 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  color: #888;
}

.italic { font-style: italic; }
.small { font-size: 0.8em; }

/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/

.lightbox {
 /** Default lightbox to hidden */
 display: none;

 /** Position and style */
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
 /** Pad the lightbox image */
 max-width: 90%;
 max-height: 80%;
 margin-top: 2%;
}

.lightbox:target {
 /** Remove default browser outline */
 outline: none;

 /** Unhide lightbox **/
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Lightbox usage markup -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h1>Pure CSS Lightbox</h1>
<p>Click the thumbnail below to activate the lightbox</p>

<!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link -->
<a href="#img1">
  <img src="https://c3.staticflickr.com/8/7315/28008413826_696528d68c.jpg " height="100" width="100" >
</a>

<!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <img src="https://c3.staticflickr.com/8/7315/28008413826_696528d68c.jpg">
</a>

<p class="italic small">Image credit: Me</p>
```

[live demo](http://codepen.io/mostofa/full/zBpoxb/)